# How can I export my social graph out of Facebook?

Tags: facebook, contacts, export

Before I contemplate deleting my Facebook account, I'd like to export my social graph (a.k.a. contacts).

What are the steps and/or recommended tools for this?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible.  The options I knew about a year ago won't work today any more.  I don't like this about facebook...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189245/fetch-email-of-a-friend-in-facebook-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier way! And yes, I tried Soocial and Plaxo which did not work as I would like and you can [check out how I set it up on my blog](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2010/07/07/the-search-for-a-single-point-of-truth.aspx).

If you go to http://memotoo.com and setup an account you can have your Facebook contacts synchronised using one of the provided applications to that service. They will then sync their server with Google and you get all of your contacts :)

I also have it synchronising contacts from Plaxo, Soocial and LinkedIn along with a plethora of other sites and apps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible.

There are facebook apps to allow you to export your friends names, without the e-mails.  some promise to give you the connection with gmail if you will give them your gmail password, I wouldn't do it if I where you.

Also, see [this thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/129/how-do-i-get-the-e-mail-addresses-of-my-facebook-friends).

Answer (score 1):

If you're a programmer, you can use the API to get easy access to most of the information from your social graph. Notably missing were email addresses, the last time I looked.

Answer (score -2):

Backupify is your friend!

> You have important data locked up in social networks and web-based applications. Backupify provides daily automatic backups, archiving, and export for all your social media and personal accounts.

I found this to be a very handy tool for getting a backup of most of my online social data.  It did a good job of collecting most of my FB data, but you will need to follow the linked work arounds to maximize the data you export:

http://www.backupify.com/tour

And the main limitation for the free account is that you "only" get to use one account **per** service (ie. if you want to back up 2 Twitter accounts you need to upgrade)

So now you shouldn't have to think twice about deleting you FB account!  :)