# How do I get the e-mail addresses of my Facebook friends?

Tags: facebook

I want to send one of my Facebook friends an e-mail, but I don't have his email-address.

It's rather personal, so I don't want to send it via Facebook if possible.

How can I get his e-mail address if it's not listed in his Profile?

Comment: The answer you have accepted is wrong, and was wrong even at the time you posted the question.

Comment: @RishabhPoddar - how do you mean it's wrong? Your answer says exactly the same as the accepted one but adds "you can sent a private message through Facebook" - which is precisely what I don't want to do.

Comment: Is it? the answer is very unclear, what is meant by "send private message with your own address"; trough which channel would you send private message?

Comment: @RishabhPoddar - It would have to be some other communication channel - text, phone even letter, or even asking friends of friends to forward the e-mail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would go against the privacy settings on Facebook. If you need a private communication channel, I suggest you send them a private message with your own address, and ask them to contact you.

Comment: I thought that might be the case.

Answer (score 0):

If the e-mail address is not listed in the Profile, there is no way you can get it From Facebook (unless you do some kind of hacking).

The only way to get his email address is to contact him (either through Facebook or some other source) and get his email address.

**OR ELSE** Facebook does has the option of sending **Private Messages** to it's users - from the User's point of view it works exactly as e-mail and from all point of views it's as secure and private as e-mails.